# For loop not working in a function with arguments

Tags: function, for

So I'm creating a function that does a for loop in all the files in a directory as a given argument and prints out all the files and directories:

```
#!/bin/bash

List () {
    for item in $1
            do
            echo "$item"
            done
}

List ~/*
```

However when I run the script it only prints out the first file in the directory.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to iterate over files in a directory you need to glob the directory like so:

```
#!/bin/bash

List () {
    for item in "${1}/"*
            do
            echo "$item"
    done
}
```

Then call it like:

```
$ list ~
```

Alternatively, if you want to pass multiple files as arguments you can write your `for` loop like this:

```
List () {
    for item
            do
            echo "$item"
    done
}
```

Which can then be called as:

```
$ list ~/*
```

---

What's wrong with your current function:

When you call it with a glob, it passes each file in the directory as a separate argument. Let's say your home directory contains `file1`, `file2`, and `file3`.  When you call `list ~/*`, you are essentially calling:

```
list ~/file1 ~/file2 ~/file3
```

Then your `for` loop is only being passed positional parameter 1 so `for item in ~/file1` and the other positional parameters are unused.

Also thanks Ilkkachu for pointing out that you also forgot a `/` in your hashbang, which I completely missed.